# Is there a proof of this question through Napoleon's theorem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Let $AC$ be a line segment in the plane and $B$ a point between $A$
>   and $C$. Construct isosceles
>       triangles $PAB$ and $QBC$ on one side of the segment $AC$ such that $\angle{APB} =\angle{BQC}= 120^o$
>       and an isosceles triangle RAC on the otherside of AC such that $\angle{ARC} = 120^o$. Show that $PQR$ is an equilateral triangle.

I saw this question on https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h57976p355627
And someone commented this:

> Isn't this just Napoleon's theorem, except the triangle is degenerate
>   (the one relating to the first fermat point?)

Others agreed with him, now I'm curious what this means.

Comment: Exactly what is means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem for a degenerate triangle $ABC$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio but when triangle $ABC$ is degenerate, the other three triangles are supposed to be equilateral, but in this question they are not. They are just isosceles with the equal angles being $30^o$

Comment: If we construct an equilateral triangle $VAB$ on the $AB$-side of $ABC$ (degenerate or not), then $\widehat{AVB}=120^\circ$ and $VA=VB$. Viceversa, if $\widehat{AVB}=120^\circ$ and $VA=VB$, then $V$ is the center of an equilateral triangle built on $AB$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you. I understood now.